# Stop Z rotation of gameObject on touch in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, rotation

Hi am trying to Rotate the gameobject in X-axis and Y-axis on touch, the code works perfectly, but it effects z-rotation also, I don't want Z-Rotation,
My gameObject does not contain Rigid-body so i can't apply Z-rotation constraints. I have searched the problem on internet but can't get any appropriate solution.
Any help would be appreciated. Thankx

Here is my code:

```
public class Rot : MonoBehaviour {
    private float RotateSpeed   = 10f;

    void OnMouseDrag () {
        float xRot = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * RotateSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        float yRot = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * RotateSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        transform.RotateAround (Vector3.up, -xRot);
        transform.RotateAround (Vector3.right, yRot);    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use another rotation algorithm or remind how works `transform.RotateAround` in official unity documentation. `transform.RotateAround` that's what rottates your gameobject arount Z-axis.

Comment: @KamikyIT can you guide me the other way rather than transform.RotateAround

Comment: Why not use transform.Rotate() or transform.localEulerAngles instead?

Comment: @SurajS I know the syntax and use of transform.Rotate() and transform.localEulerAngles, but can u give me a clue how to use it in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-xRot,yRot,0.0f),Space.Self);
```

If you want to set absolute rotation use `transform.localEulerAngles`